# How to convert wstring to wchar_t*? C++

Tags: c++, wchar-t, wstring

I would like to convert wstring to wchar_t*. I have tried everything what i know, please help.
I would like to convert wstring to wchar_t*.

Comment: According to the manual you can obtaine a pointer like this: [std::wstring::c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Answer (score 7):

Did you try reading the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

```
const wchar_t* wcs = s.c_str();
```

Comment: The OP apparently wants a `wchar_t*`, not a `wchar_t const*`, as illustrated in this answer. Starting with C++17, [wstring::data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) provides that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to convert `wstring` to `wchar_t*` but you can convert it to `const wchar_t*` which is what [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44985479/841330) by K.Kirsz says.

This is by design because you can access a const pointer but you shouldn't manipulate the pointer. See a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919626/can-i-get-a-non-const-c-string-back-from-a-c-string/21354932#comment103509456_21354932) and its answers.

The best bet is to create a new string using [_wcsdup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strdup-wcsdup-mbsdup?view=vs-2019) and access the non const buffer, an ascii example is given there.

For unicode:

```
    wstring str = L"I am a unicode string";
    wchar_t* ptr = _wcsdup(str.c_str());
    // use ptr here....
    free(ptr); // free memory when done
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same question and arrived here. Posting my answer a few years later, but this works:

```
std::wstring wname1 = L"wide string";
wchar_t wname2[1024];
wcscpy(wname2, wname1.c_str());
wchar_t* pfoo = new wchar_t[1024];
wcscpy(pfoo, wname1.c_str());
```